# Jquery show & hide instead of toggle

Tags: jquery

Well as you will see I´m a designer not a programmer, so don´t be tough with me.
I have a toggle that works pretty well, but I can´t launch a simple show and hide script.
I´m a looser...
The thing is that H4 with toggle function works well, independently. But I need also to display all and hide all by pressing two buttons.

**The toggle effect**

```
$(function() {
    $('.toggle-item').each(function(ix, el) {

        $(this).addClass('inactive');
        var contentDiv = $('.toggle-content', $(el));
        $(this).attr('data-height', contentDiv.outerHeight());
        contentDiv.css('overflow', 'hidden');
        contentDiv.height(0);
    });

    $(".toggle-item h4").click(function(){
        var $parent = $(this).parent('.toggle-item');
        if($parent.length) {
            if( $parent.hasClass('inactive') ) {
                $parent.removeClass('inactive');
                $('.toggle-content', $parent).height(           $parent.attr('data-height'));
            } else {
                $parent.addClass('inactive');
                $('.toggle-content', $parent).height( 0 );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**The HTML code:**

```
<div class="toggle-item">
    <h4>SOME TEXT AS HEADLINE</h4>
    <div class="toggle-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras accumsan, turpis facilisis ultricies consequat, tellus ligula sagittis libero, porttitor venenatis urna dui non quam. Fusce aliquam, libero sed eleifend pellentesque, ligula dolor porta neque, et egestas diam mauris id odio.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The buttons**

```
<button id="show">Show All</button> 
<button id="hide">Hide All</button>
```

**The intent**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#show").click( function() {
       $('.toggle-content').show();
  });
  $("#hide").click(function(){
       $('.toggle-content').hide();
  });
});
```

[Here](http://yosoy.mitiendy.com/posts/cosmetica-facial?test=1) you can find the example running.

Any hints are welcome!
TIA.

Comment: You lost me... I don't see anything wrong with the code in "The Intent". What are you trying to do that it's not doing?

Comment: please create a http://jsFiddle.net or a http://jsbin.com demo And describe a bit better what's your issue

Comment: yeah lost me too, as this works in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DfprZ/)

Comment: I think the issue you're running into is that you set the height of the content to 0, so even when you do show it, it still isn't visible. You might want to `.animate()` the height or something. It's looks like you are saving the original height, so it shouldn't be too difficult

Comment: ...still lost, as your "the toggle effect" script also works in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sst4Q/) when you click on the `SOME TEXT AS HEADLINE`

Comment: Have you tried both scripts? this is H4 sould open independtly, and, should open all and hide all. and this not happen. http://jsfiddle.net/DfprZ/
If you want I can´t put the real test link.

Comment: Sorry... This is the JSF link: http://jsfiddle.net/DfprZ/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, vía Mr Manuel Cebrian, from Tiendy.com comes the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#show").click( function() {
       $('.toggle-item').each(function(i) {             
            $(this).removeClass('inactive');
            $('.toggle-content', this).height( $(this).attr('data-height'));
       });
  });

  $("#hide").click(function(){
       $('.toggle-item').each(function(i) {
            $(this).addClass('inactive');
            $('.toggle-content', this).height( 0 );
       });
  });

});
```

This will open and close all, some opened will closed also. Big thanks for Mr Cebrian, and hope this helps someone more.
Thanks you all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this, just try updating your script to as below:

```
  $("#show").click( function() {
       $('.toggle-content').each(function(){
         // you need this because height goes to 0pt
         $(this).height('auto');
         $(this).show();
       });
  });
  $("#hide").click(function(){
       $('.toggle-content').each(function(){
         $(this).hide();
       });
  });
```

I hoep this would help

Comment: Didn´t help :| 
As you can see just close... but didn´t work. Follow the link to see it. ID´s originals are #mostrar and #ocultar, I´ve changed but without luck. Anyway thanks!